# Unexpected test behavior in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have test and I want to use `if/else`:

```
   public function testLocal() {

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('')
                ->type('cro_user_email', '1')
                ->type('cro_user_password', '1')
                ->press('LOG IN')
                ->pause(1500)
                ->click('div > section.c-clients > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a')
                ->click('td.tablesaw-swipe-cellpersist > a');


            if ($browser->assertVisible('div > nav > a > i')) {
                    $browser->click('div > nav > a > i');

            } elseif ($browser->assertMissing('div > nav > a > i')) {
            $browser->quit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Problem is, my IDE is showing me this error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body div > nav > a > i"}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is inside the if condition:

```
if ($browser->assertVisible('div > nav > a > i')) {
```

The code `$browser->assertVisible('div > nav > a > i')` will not return true/false, but rather true or throw an exception.

Instead of doing if/else use exception handling like this:

```
try {
    $browser->assertVisible('div > nav > a > i');
} catch (\Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException $exception) {
    $browser->assertMissing('div > nav > a > i');
}
$browser->quit();
```